# python implementation of 'readAsDataURL

Tags: python, uri, filereader

i'm having some troubles to get the URI from a certain file, like .mp4/.ogg/etc..
The thing is that i need to do it in python, where the webserver is running.

Initially, i proceed like this:

```
def __parse64(self, path_file):
    string_file = open(path_file, 'r').readlines()
    new_string_file = ''
    for line in string_file:
        striped_line = line.strip()
        separated_lines = striped_line.split('\n')
        new_line = ''
        for l in separated_lines:
            new_line += l
        new_string_file += new_line
    self.encoded_string_file = b64.b64encode(new_string_file)
```

But this way, doesn't give what i need, if you compare the result with given [here.](http://datauri.com/)

What a i need is a way to implement the function readAsDataURL() from FileReader class (see the code of the link above), in python.

**UPDATE:**
The solution given by @SeanVieira, returns a valid data field for the URI.

```
def __parse64(self, path_file):
    file_data = open(path_file, 'rb').read(-1) 
    self.encoded_string_file = b64.b64encode(file_data)
```

Now how can i complete the URI, with the previous fields?
Like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format).

For example: data:video/mp4;base64,data

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are treating binary-encoded data as text data, which is breaking your code.

Try:

```
def __parse64(self, path_file):
    file_data = open(path_file, 'rb').read(-1) 
    #This slurps the whole file as binary.
    self.encoded_string_file = b64.b64encode(file_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction! now it seems a lot like the result of readAsDataURL, but still not equal. When parsing an .mp4 file, the beginning of the string (result) have the same characters: AAAAHGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAA....(and so on), but it changes, and their length also is different. 728420 (python) vs 1464184 (js). Any ideas?

Comment: It's working! i don't understand why is that difference, but the result is working. I ran a test through video tag, with the given uri and it's shinning. The only thing is missing is the first URI part, which in the test i already know it: data:video/mp4;base64,data. How could i find it?

Comment: @Nacho -- I'd just use the mimetypes library (included in Python) to guess the file type and add `"data:" + mimetype + ";base64," + data` together myself.  http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type

Comment: @Nacho -- Huzzah! Glad I could help! Don't forget click the checkbox underneath the `0` (and click the up arrow ["upvote"] if you thought it particularly helpful).

Comment: @cheziHoyzer - understood! The OP is "how do I encode a file's contents as a Base64-encoded string and determine it's mime-type".  Is there something that this answer leaves out that fails that case, or is your warning related to the fact that sometimes `file_data` may be very large and cause memory pressure? (Or is there some other problem entirely?)

Comment: Yes, turn out the problem was memory, I solved it in other way (after hours of understanding why your answer is not working for me)

Comment: @cheziHoyzer - yes, that's a separate problem and question.  I didn't want to clutter up the answer with covering scaling cases that are important but hide the steps that need to be taken (back pressure when the disk is slow, streaming the contents when the file is too large, etc.)

Comment: I am curious though - what was the particular problems you were running into so that reading the file byte-by-byte into a `bytearray` worked but slurping it didn't?  Because that really sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The @SeanVieria answer will not work if the file is very large (more than 7mb)

This function will work for all cases (tested on Python version 3.4):

```
def __parse64(self, path_file):
        data = bytearray()
        with open(path_file, "rb") as f:
            b = f.read(1)
            while b != b"":
                data.append(int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big'))
                b = f.read(1)
        self.encoded_string_file = base64.b64encode(data)
```